# How to give a role to a role - "arn:aws:sts::913xxxxx71:assumed-role"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks

I am following these instructions in order to send our EKS cluster logs to CloudWatch:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-logs.html

Since it wasn't working I ran the suggested to command to tail the logs for one of the fluentd pods:

```
kubectl logs fluentd-cloudwatch-fc7vx -n amazon-cloudwatch
```

I am seeing this error:

> error_class=Aws::CloudWatchLogs::Errors::AccessDeniedException
>   error="User:
>   arn:aws:sts::913xxxxx71:assumed-role/eksctl-prod-nodegroup-standard-wo-NodeInstanceRole-1ESBFXHSI966X/i-0937e3xxxx07ea6
>   is not authorized to perform: logs:DescribeLogGroups on resource:
>   arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:913617820371:log-group::log-stream:"

I have a role that has the right permissions, but how can I give the role to the `arn:aws:sts::913xxxxx71:assumed-role/eksctl-prod-nodegroup-standard-wo-NodeInstanceRole-1ESBFXHSI966X/i-0937e3xxxx07ea6` user?

Comment: Have you considered to use IRSA? in that way, your POD will use a service Account that will assume an IAM role and you aren't giving permissions for the whole node and all pods running inside that node

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform step to attach the CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy policy to cluster worker node role documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-prerequisites.html

Comment: I also need to restart the ec2 instances of the k8s cluster to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to assume the role.  This can be done a few different ways:

1. You can setup an [AWS profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) and use that to execute commands as a different role.
2. You can use a tool like [awsudo](https://github.com/makethunder/awsudo)

One caveat is the the role you are assuming must have a trust relationship setup so that is permits others to assume it.  There is an example of this trust relationship setup in the link for (1) above.

**That being said, you probably shouldn't be doing any of this for your use case.**

If your other role is in a state where it needs to be updated to allow assumption, it is going to be much easier and more secure for you to just update the `eksctl-prod-nodegroup-standard-wo-NodeInstanceRole-1ESBFXHSI966X` role directly with the permissions you need.

Ideally you can associate the role with the same policy that is attached to the other role with the desired permissions.

Comment: yeah I think I needed to give a policy to the role